# Prevent Triggers Being Fired Simultaneously

Tags: c#, quartz.net, job-scheduling

Is there a way to tell Quartz.NET not to fire two triggers at the same time? That means if trigger `A` and trigger `B` have the exact same schedule, then trigger `B` waits a certain amount of time and then fire?

I have seen in my program that this can cause an issue when both my jobs are reading from the same file and executing the same `.exe` file.  This causes an uncaught exception that I am yet to figure out.

I am not sure how Quartz.NET handles this. But is there a way to delay such triggers (even if it's just for a few seconds)?

Comment: Quartz.NET manages concurrency not at scheduler level but using attributes that can be added to your Job class. `[DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute]` avoids execution of multiple instances of a given job concurrently. Alternatively, inside each job, you can synchronize access to shared resources using `Mutex` or `ReaderWriterLock`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/?topic=html/89688e7d-3f32-fb19-c3b1-0e05e479a10d.htm) for your job.

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute]
class DisallowConcurrentJob : IJob
{
   //Implementation goes here
}
```

> It prevents multiple instances of a job **WITH THE SAME KEY** from running
>   at the same time.

A very good explanation can be found [here](http://jayvilalta.com/blog/2014/06/04/understanding-the-disallowconcurrentexecution-job-attribute/).

**UPDATE:**

If you want to be sure that the trigger/job always runs you can use [misfire](http://java.dzone.com/articles/quartz-scheduler-misfire) instructions:

```
IJobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.Create<InheritedJob1>()
    .WithIdentity("DisallowConcurrentJob", "MYGROUP")
    .RequestRecovery(true)
    .Build();

//Schedule this job to execute every second, a maximum of 5 times
ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.RepeatSecondlyForTotalCount(5)
        .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
    .StartNow()
    .WithIdentity("DisallowConcurrentJobTrigger", "MYGROUP")
    .Build();

Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
```

**WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow**

```
The job is executed immediately after the scheduler discovers misfire situation.
```

Comment: But these are not jobs with the same key.

Comment: When you use DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute, does that mean the other job will wait or simply not be run?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem indeed not misfiring. Because I can see that the program has been run. But due to some uncaught error is terminated. So what I need is not a misfire policy, but a way to make simultaneous jobs be run with a slight delay.

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid 2 jobs (same key) running at the same time but delay those in conflict. Basically all job will run - at some point - you won't miss a trigger.